# Select from dynamic table into Datatable Oracle

Tags: .net, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm looking to do a simple select statement to get back all the data from a table in oracle. Due to the nature of the ongoing project, the tables are constantly being updated and changed so I don't have any solid designs.

I'm looking for a simple statement. This is all I need it to do.

```
Select * from myVariable
```

After searching I got this to compile

```
create or replace procedure "GET_TABLEINFO" (o_rc OUT sys_refcursor, inTableName IN varchar2) AS       

BEGIN
      execute immediate 
          'SELECT * FROM '||inTableName
      using inTableName;
  END;
```

but when I try to add it to a data table:

```
using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.InitialLONGFetchSize = 1000;
            cmd.CommandText = "GET_TABLEINFO";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("o_rc", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("inTable", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 60, inTableName, ParameterDirection.Input);

            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);
```

I get this

Edit:

I'm not sure how to set the cursor (first time using oracle, usually use SQLSERVER). The procedure should be simple. I pass in the table name, and I need to get the data from that table. Nothing fancy, no where clauses etc.

> ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist ORA-06512: at
>   "ODS_DEV.GET_TABLEINFO", line 4 ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: Is that the whole SP? You're not setting output for the sys_refcursor. Also what is the "using inTableName;". Is this from the c# code? Could you fix the post to clarify what the procedure is doing?

Comment: The using inTableName was the only way I could get it to compile

Comment: The `using` clause is for bind variables, but your example doesn't have any, hence the ' bind variable does not exist' error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_TABLEINFO(o_rc OUT sys_refcursor, inTableName IN varchar2) AS       
    sqlquery VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
    sqlquery := 'SELECT * FROM ' || inTableName;
    OPEN o_rc FOR sqlquery;
END;
```

Comment: I spent hours looking for this... Thank you a million.

Answer (score 3):

Table names (and column names) cannot be bind variables.  Presumably, you also want the SQL statement that you build to be used to open the cursor `o_rc`. Your stored procedure would need to be something like

```
create or replace procedure GET_TABLEINFO (
  o_rc OUT sys_refcursor, 
  inTableName IN varchar2) 
AS       
BEGIN
  OPEN o_rc
   FOR 'SELECT * FROM '||inTableName;
END;
```

Of course, this would leave the system terribly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  At a minimum, you'd want to throw in an extra `dbms_assert` call

```
create or replace procedure GET_TABLEINFO (
  o_rc OUT sys_refcursor, 
  inTableName IN varchar2) 
AS       
BEGIN
  OPEN o_rc
   FOR 'SELECT * FROM '|| dbms_assert.sql_object_name( inTableName );
END;
```